# Elimination reaction of 1-bromo-2-phenylcyclopentane

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

> In the following reaction, treating the *trans*-1-bromo-2-phenylcyclopentane with ethanolic KOH gives an alkene. But in this case, the double bond is on the left side (less substituted) instead of being the more substituted one. 
>   [image]

But why does this happen? Zaitsev's rule favours the highly substituted alkene. Even if a carbocation is formed, a hydride shift would have landed it on the carbon with the phenyl group, as the carbocation would be stabilised by resonance. Does the *trans* configuration forbid such reaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three common elimination mechanisms: $\mathrm{E1, E2}$ and $\mathrm{E1_{cb}}$. $\mathrm{E1}$ and $\mathrm{E1_{cb}}$ both imply that an ionic intermediate is formed first; $\mathrm{E1}$ implies the same carbocationic intermediate as in an $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction. The $\mathrm{cb}$ in $\mathrm{E1_{cb}}$ means *conjugate base,* i.e. the first step is deprotonation of the compound to give an carbanionic intermediate.

$\mathrm{E1}$ reactions require good leaving groups and a moderately stabilised carbocation; this is not the case in your reactant.

$\mathrm{E1_{cb}}$ requires a very strong base and an at least mildly stabilised anion; this is not the case with your reagent and reactant.

Thus, the mechanism must be according to $\mathrm{E2}$, where the abstraction of a proton and the displacement of the leaving group happen at the same time. $\mathrm{E2}$ mechanisms require a $180^\circ$ anti-periplanar configuration of the $\ce{Br-C-C-H}$ bonds for easier attack and favour those double bonds where the hydrogen is less stericly hindered. Additionally, your reactant is *trans*-configured, thus meaning that there is no available proton on the higher-substituted carbon that can participate in elimination. Altogether, this leads to $\mathrm{E2}$ eliminations generally following **Hofmann’s rule** rather than Zaitsev’s rule. Hofmann initially observed what later became the Hofmann rule in the Hofmann elimination, which follows an $\mathrm{E2}$ mechanism.

As the ethanolic $\ce{KOH}$ is not strong enough to isomerise the double bond, the Hofmann product will be observed.

Comment: The carbocation formed by releasing $\ce{Br^-}$ ion will be a secondary carbocation. So how can we say that it will not be a stable one, as the relative order of stability is tertiary>secondary>primary (ignoring resonance effects, if any, of the benzene ring)?

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti Assume only tertiary and benzylic (maybe allylic) carbocations to be stable enough to be formed. Everything else would immediately undergo Wagner-Meerwein rearrangements.

Comment: Well, if there is a carbocation formed, and there is a rearrangement, then, the charge will be shifted to the attaching point of the benzene and cyclopentane ring, as it gives maximum stability(tertiary and also resonance). Then the products will also change.

Comment: @ShoubhikRajMaiti But that is not observed since the reaction is much slower than the one by E2.

Answer (score 1):

The product structure is wrong, the Br should be gone.

There's no carbokation here, this is a reaction with E2-mechanism, which works best if the abstracted hydrogen is at a dihedral angle of 180° to the leaving group.

Comment: Then the choice of product between 3-Phenylcyclopentene and 1-Phenylcyclopentene would depend upon the diastereomer, right? I was thinking about an E1-mechanism here...

Comment: Yes, if you use the cis compound you will get the double bond on the other position.

Comment: The update in the figure in the question clears all doubts.

Comment: @DSVA A more elaborate answer would have been helpful.